# If a Fourier Transform is continuous in frequency, then what are the "harmonics"?

Tags: fourier-analysis

The basic idea of a Fourier series is that you use integer multiples of some fundamental frequency to represent any time domain signal.

[image: Haykin page 253]

Ok, so if the Fourier Transform (Non periodic, continuous in time, or non periodic, discrete in time) results in a *continuum* of frequencies, then uh, is there no fundamental frequency / concept of using integer multiples of some fundamental frequency?

Comment: Nope. Pretty much by definition, right?

Comment: The Fourier *series* deals with discrete fundamentals and harmonics of periodic functions.  The Fourier *transform* is a continuous generalization to non-periodic functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to talk about a fundamental frequency, you need a fundamental **period**. But the Fourier transform deals with integrable functions ($L^1$, or $L^2$ if you go further in the theory) defined on the whole real line, and they are not periodic (except the zero function).